# Post multipart/form-data using python file difficulties

Tags: post, python-2.7, windows-7, python-requests, multipartform-data

I have been trying to automate the renumbering of pdb-files using a numbering server called [Abnum](http://www.bioinf.org.uk/abs/abnum/). They state: To number a structure you must pass parameters in POST format and use enctype="multipart/form-data". It does work for a single sequence, but uploading the pdb-file(plain-text file) remains a problem.

My code:

```
import requests
rel_path = "PDB_mono"
rel_path2 = "1A5F.pdb"
i = os.path.abspath(__file__)
g = os.getcwd()
mypath = os.path.join(g,rel_path)
mypath = os.path.join(mypath,rel_path2)
print mypath
url = 'http://www.bioinf.org.uk/cgi-bin/abnum/abnumpdb.pl?plain=1&pdb=1A5F.pdb&scheme=-a&output=-l'
files = {'file': open('1A5F.pdb', 'rb')}
r=requests.post(url, files={'file': open(mypath)}).content
print r
```

Myfile:

```
mypath =F:\Leuven\Python\PDB_mono\1A5F.pdb
```

Response:

```
<html>    
<head>
   <title>AbNum results</title>    
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='/bo.css' />    
</head>    

<body>    
<h1>Abnum: PDB numbering</h1>         

<h3>There was an error in your submission</h3>

<pre>    
Either the PDB file you specified did not exist, or contained no ATOM records    
</pre>

<p>Click the browser "Back" button to return to the form and correct your error.</p>    
</body>    
</html>

</body>    
</html>
```

I'm using Windows 7, python 2.7.

I would really appreciate a response, or at least some pointing in the right direction

example PDB file:

[pdb file](http://www.pdb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=1a0q)

You can download it on the right as a text file. It's a simple file containing coordinates of atoms

Comment: Are you able to upload this file using the web interface and a browser with no difficulties? I don't have an example pdb file to test with, and understanding how to post to their endpoint isn't too well documented on the site.

Comment: I have no problems using the web interface, but automating it remains a problem for me. I added a link to a PDB file. Any help or tips is much appreciated